# Resend data in post method to another Pages PHP

Tags: php, post, confirm, savechanges, .data

I have a page to register a person's data. In that page i have a button (Register) that send the data in a HTML FORM (in POST method) to a search for similar pages.

If have no equal matches in the SQL data base (id card) the server reply `no match` (document number) but shows the most similar names.

In the end of the reply page i put a button to confirm the save operation, but i'm in the client side now.

How i do resend the data that i received before to another page (where i'll save in SQL) in the post (various items name, birth, address, etc - not only one data) method?

Comment: you can put the data in hidden input fields of the form that the second submit button sends.

Comment: Or you could temporarily put the data in the PHP session, ready to use again with the user's next request.

Comment: Ok. The hidden inputs field could be the option, because i do have other data in session and i do not want to close session until the user end os journey. Thank you both.

Comment: _"because i do have other data in session and i do not want to close session until the user end os journey"_ - who said you had to close it, you can simply _remove_ part of the session data again, after you are done processing it.

Comment: Remember, session is an array to PHP, so place this in a sensibly named sub array so you can easily control it and know where it is

Comment: Ok. Thank you all. Because i'm new on php all off your solutions realy help me.

Comment: Best regards, For all